# Producer - multiple consumer implementation using futures

Tags: scala, concurrency, producer-consumer

I've tried to implement a producer-multiple consumer pattern using futures and I was wondering should it ever deadlock, and if it should, why?

I have this method `RunNTimes` which I implemented in order to run the implementation, e.g. 1000 times with 500 consumers.

The implementation shouldn't deadlock as far as I know and it often doesn't (running it multiple times and telling `RunNTime`s to repeat for 1000 times). However, every once in a while it blocks at the first or second run (I'm running it from sbt). For the sake of simplicity, ignore the `RunNTimes` method, I've included it only to explain why the occasional deadlock seems strange to me.

```
package comparison_examples.futuresimplementation

import common.MeasurementHelpers._
import common._

import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.concurrent.blocking
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future, Promise}

case class Item(value: Int)

object ProducerConsumer {

    private val sharedQueue = mutable.Queue[Item]()

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val n: Double = if (args.nonEmpty) args(0).toDouble else Configuration.runTimes.toDouble
        val numConsumers = if (args.length == 2) args(1).toInt else Configuration.numberOfConsumers

        val funRunNTimes = MeasurementHelpers.runNTimes(n.toInt) _

        val results = funRunNTimes {

            val p = Promise[Boolean]()

            val producer = new Producer(p, sharedQueue)
            val cs = startConsumers(numConsumers, List[Consumer](), sharedQueue, p)

            val fp = producer.start()
            val fs = cs.map(x => x.start())

            val f = Future.sequence(fs)

            Await.result(fp, Duration.Inf)
            Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)

            val allElementsObtained = cs.flatMap(_.getObtainedItems)

            println(allElementsObtained.length)
        }

        println(s"Run times: $n")
        println(s"Average number of distinct threads: ${results.map(x => x._3.length).sum / n }")
        println(s"Average duration: ${results.map(x => x._2).sum / n} milliseconds")

        println()
    }

    def startConsumers(max: Int, result: List[Consumer], sharedQueue: mutable.Queue[Item], p: Promise[Boolean]): List[Consumer] =
         if (max == 0) result
         else {
             val consumer = new Consumer(p, sharedQueue)

             startConsumers(max - 1, consumer :: result, sharedQueue, p)
        }
 }

class Producer(p: Promise[Boolean], sharedQueue: mutable.Queue[Item]) {

def start(): Future[Unit] = Future {

    val n = Configuration.workToProduce

        for (i <- 1 to n) {

            val item = Item(i)

                sharedQueue.synchronized {

                    sharedQueue.enqueue(item)
                    sharedQueue.notifyAll()
                }
        }

    p success true
}
}

class Consumer(p: Promise[Boolean], sharedQueue: mutable.Queue[Item]) {

private var obtainedItems = List[Item]()

def getObtainedItems: List[Item] = obtainedItems

def start(): Future[Unit] = Future {

    addCurrentThread()

        while (sharedQueue.nonEmpty || !p.isCompleted) {

            obtainedItems = getItem match {

                case None => obtainedItems
                case Some(item) => item :: obtainedItems
            }
        }
}

def getItem: Option[Item] = blocking {

    sharedQueue.synchronized {

        while (sharedQueue.isEmpty && !p.isCompleted) {

            sharedQueue.wait()
        }

        val result = if (sharedQueue.nonEmpty)
            Some(sharedQueue.dequeue())
        else
            None

        sharedQueue.notifyAll()

        result
    }
}


def printObtainedItems(): Unit =
    obtainedItems.foreach(x => print(s"\t ${x.value}"))
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice several things.

You have a data race on the shared queue. The consumer has an unsynchronized access to the `nonEmpty` property.

The `notifyAll` after you removed an element from the queue is unnecessary. Consumers shouldn't care about other consumers removing items.

But the main problem, which is suspect is the source of your deadlocks, is the race condition between the producer and the consumers. Here's what I think happens:

1. The producer produces the last item. It notifies all threads, releases the lock, but is preempted before setting the promise.
2. Consumer C1 wakes up, sees the queue is non-empty and grabs the element. It notifies all threads, releases the lock, and goes out to add the element to its list.
3. The other consumers wake up, see that the queue is empty but the promise is not set, and go back to sleep.
4. The producer sets the promise.
5. Consumer C1 sees that the promise is set and terminates.
6. The other consumers continue sleeping for all eternity.

To solve this, you need to `notifyAll` after you've set the promise. You can also probably optimize the whole thing by only calling `notifyOne` after adding an element.

Comment: seems that the issue has been resolved, I tried running with 1000 repeats and 5000 consumers, not one deadlocked. Thank you, I will edit the code in the original question.